# How to deploy laravel 8 web app to google cloud with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, cloud

I have a laravel application in local. I want to deploy this web app to google cloud. domain settings and I don't know what to do. I also have mysql database. An application that users can use in the internet environment where they can log in. what should i do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run Laravel on Google App Engine standard environment.
You should check https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard